# Update same table in parallel using batch number pl-sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

Edit 1 (Adding code snippet):

I am taking the stats, took some sets of stats, most probably, it is taking the same time irrespective of the parallel hint.

```
CREATE TABLE temp_i_sept nologging parallel 15 as
SELECT distinct  t1.a,t1.b,t1.c,t1.d,t1.e,t1.f,t1.g,
schema1.package1.func1(t1.e,t1.f,t1.g,t1.h,t1.i, t1.j 
,t1.k,t1.l,t1.m,t1.n*1000,t1.o, t1.p,t1.q,t1.r,t1.s ,t1.t)/1000 u, 
t1.v
FROM temp_i_sep17 t1
WHERE t1.w IS NULL;
```

I have this statement,

```
create table TWO nologging parallel 15 as
select a, b, c, pkg_xyz(l,m,n) d
from ONE;
```

As you can see, there is a package call in the select query.
There are 7 million rows in table ONE.

It is taking approx 3.5 hours to execute. It is being called from a shell script via sqlplus.
I need to optimise it.

I can make batches using NTILE and then try to induce some parallelism. I can calculate the value d by invoking the pkg_xyz and update the value.
Say I made 10 batches via NTILE, now how can I initiate 10 separate update statements to act on the same table, based on the batch_num?

Comment: Show us the code of your stored procedure. **[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: To enable parallel processing for functions, need to use parallel_enable clause in the function. This link helped. The script which was taking 3 hours got completed in 16 minutes now. 

https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/parallel-plsql-functions-and-global-temporary-tables-and-wrong-results
Integrated Cloud